# Qt: Draw text with different fonts

Tags: c++, qt

I'm using  `void QPainter::drawText(const QRectF &rectangle, const QString &text, const QTextOption &option = QTextOption()` method to draw some text. 
It lets me to align text as i wish (in the center of `rectangle`, for example).

Now, i need to do the same thing, except i need to draw one part of `text` with
some font and the other part with another. 
For example, if text is "Hello world", i want "Hello" to be drawn with Arial and "World" with Times New Roman, but it should still be aligned with the center of `rectangle`.

What is the best way to achieve that?

Comment: It will be really helpful if you can share your codes, and issue where you are stuck and what have you done to solve the same...
It seems a help me with my homework question...

Comment: You just need to setPen(Qt::blue) before calling drawText with a subtext

Comment: You might want to look at how `QLabel` (for example) handles `Qt::RichText`.

Comment: You might actually want to just use `QLabel` for almost all of your image and text displaying needs. There are also a couple of built-in ways to achieve centering the label as you want, depending on what exactly you want. `QGridLayout` is probably easiest, as it allows overlapping nested layouts and widgets.

Answer (score 1):

you can try with this :

```
 QPainter painter(this);
 painter.setFont(QFont("Arial", 12));
 painter.drawText(rect(), Qt::AlignCenter, "Hello");
```